# Sencha Ext JS Date Panel Year Picker Config

Tags: javascript, extjs

Is there a way to specificity the minimum and maximum years for the [year picker](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/modern/Ext.panel.YearPicker.html) on the [date panel](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/modern/Ext.panel.Date.html)? I've played with `store` and `data` in the [configs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/modern/Ext.panel.YearPicker.html#configs) but to no avail.

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/31ai)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can specify the config for the yearpicker and include a start and end year there.

```
        xtype:'datepanel',
        yearPicker: {
            start: 2007,
            end: 2020
        }
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/31aj)